# Tableau relationship data model

Tags: mysql, tableau-api, relationship, datamodel

Please help me with the below issue that I have in Tableau while trying to construct the relationship data model between 4 separate tables(source mySQL):

Dim_Partners,
Fact_General_Contracts,
Fact_Additional_Contracts,
Dim_ThirdParty

I have a main dim table with the names of several partners, primary key Partner_ID. The tables General_Contracts and Additional_Contracts contain this field, so I can do a relationship between all 3 using this key. The problem is that I need to link a fourth table, Dim_ThirdParty, which is another dimension table, that contains the primary key ThirdParty_ID, and I need to link it to the two fact tables, General_Contracts, and Additional_Contracts.

How can I do this efficiently in Tableau? In Power BI the solution is very simple, as you are able to create multiple links between tables. But in Tableau?

I tried connecting the main dimension table Partners to the two Dim tables (see print screen attached), but how can I link the second dim Table, without having to link it to each table separately, resulting in a weird-looking data model? Would it be better to join each fact table in the logical layer?

[image]

Comment: have a look at this : https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/datasource_multitable_normalized.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau doesn't support any kind of relationship arrangement where you can trace a circle around the tables involved (as you would have if Dim_ThirdParty were a single point in your diagram).

You have two options to resolve this:

1. Union Fact_General_Contracts and Fact_Additional_Contracts into a single table with an additional column to allow measures to distinguish between the two (or suitable count columns with 0\null for the wrong row types).
2. Use a cross join to merge Dim_Partners and Dim_ThirdParty leaving you with a single dimension holding every valid combination of the two and then join to both fact tables on the pair of keys.